# listview setOnItemClickListner isn't working not moving to another activity

Tags: android

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/friends",
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    // Insert your code here

```
                JSONObject jsonobject =response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    String data=jsonobject.getString("data");
                    JSONArray array= new JSONArray(data);
                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {

                        jsonFriend      =array.getJSONObject(i);
                        for (int j=0 ; j <array.length();j++){
                            friend=new Friend();
                            friend.setId(jsonFriend.getString("id"));
                            friend.setName(jsonFriend.getString("name"));


                            JSONObject pictureObject=jsonFriend.getJSONObject("picture");
                            JSONObject pictureDataObject=pictureObject.getJSONObject("data");

                            PictureData pictureData=new PictureData() ;

                            Data data1=new Data();
                            data1.setUrl(pictureDataObject.getString("url"));


                            pictureData.setData(data1);
                            friend.setPictureData(pictureData);
                        }
                        friendmodelarraylist.add(friend);

                    }
                    ResponseAdapter adapter =new ResponseAdapter(friendmodelarraylist,HomeActivity.this);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,FriendQuestios.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

}

here is my manfist.xml` this prog must get fb friends in listview and it does but i couldnot click any item of this list

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".activies.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activies.HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activies.FriendQuestios"></activity>
```

Comment: Do you have some log?

Comment: nothing wrong with the code ,it just doesn't respond to my clicks
that's what happen when it's clicked

app:id/list_friends}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=267.4428, y[0]=210.61053, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=39461958, downTime=39461838, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }

Comment: Show us your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any focusable widget like edittext in your custom_list_item? It can be because of it. Try edittext focusable=false or replace with textview or anything.

Comment: i have  textview and image view but i donot why it's not working , ihave tried it alot and worked corretcly